# React Native ART library cause application crash

Tags: react-native

If I create a new empty react-native project with this code in App.js, application will be crashed, without providing any error.

```
import React from 'react'
import { ART, View } from 'react-native'

const { Surface, Group, Shape } = ART

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Surface width={200} height={100}>
                    <Group x={0} y={0}>
                        <Shape
                            d={"M-68.9646319937036,-29.476762610114324A75,75,0,0,1,-49.345310456503256,-56.48044206582762L-20.635195356782273,-21.775874553905552A30,30,0,0,0,-27.086713440010442,-12.896121704557451Z"}
                            stroke={"#2ca02c"}
                            strokeWidth={3}
                        />
                    </Group>
                </Surface>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Am I use ART library incorrectly? I also tried

```
react-native link art
```

but it didn't work.

```
Packages:
  react-native: 0.49.3
  react: 16.0.0-beta.5

Target Platform: Android Emulator - Nexus_5x_API_26_x86
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by using software graphics emulation in the AVD properties